# Jdeveloper integrated weblogic server doesn't start

Tags: jdeveloper

I've created an adf project and just added some jsp pages that I wanted to just look at, but I can't get the weblogic server to start. In the console, I get:

> [Starting IntegratedWebLogicServer.] [waiting for the server to
>   complete its initialization...] The syntax of the command is
>   incorrect. Process exited.[IntegratedWebLogicServer terminated.]

Testing the connection, I get this:

> Testing JSR-160 Runtime                ... failed
>
> Cannot establish connection.
>
> Testing JNDI                           ... skipped
>
> Testing JSR-160 DomainRuntime          ... skipped
>
> Testing JSR-160 Edit                   ... skipped
>
> Testing HTTP                           ... failed
>
> Connection refused: connect
>
> Testing JSR-88                         ... skipped
>
> Testing JSR-88-LOCAL                   ... skipped
>
> Testing Server MBeans Model            ... skipped
>
> Testing App Controller                 ... skipped
>
> Testing JSR-88-DEP-MGR                 ... skipped
>
> Testing JSR-88-DEP-MGR-LOCAL           ... skipped
>
> 0 of 11 tests successful.

Anyone know why? Also what these tests mean? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Jdeveloper 12c installed. I uninstalled it (deleted related files as well) and installed 11g. Ran the server by going Run > Start Server Instance. Server managed to start up after like 5 minutes. Ran the tests again:

> Testing JSR-160 Runtime                ... success
>
> Testing JSR-160 DomainRuntime          ... success
>
> Testing JSR-88                         ... success
>
> Testing JSR-88-LOCAL                   ... success
>
> Testing JNDI                           ... success
>
> Testing JSR-160 Edit                   ... success
>
> Testing HTTP                           ... success
>
> Testing Server MBeans Model            ... success
>
> Testing App Controller                 ... success
>
> 9 of 9 tests successful.